# Use a model in a component

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I use a model in a component in CakePHP?

In a controller you can use

```
public $uses = array(...);
```

but that doesn't work in a Component.

What does?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Yourmodel');
```

Simple query with your model into your component

```
$result= $model->find('all');
```

Comment: you are welocome @LucPrevoo

Comment: better `Yourmodel` (uppercase)

Answer (score 14):

You could do it this way:

```
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```

But it is suppose you don't use Models inside components.

Comment: why you advice to not use model inside component?

Comment: When you start using more than one Model in a component it might be better to use a behavior.

Comment: it always depends on the specific use case. the question does not reveal too much, though.

Comment: +1 since you are unlucky fellow. @AlessandroMinoccheri and you added the answer same time. But you didn't get much votes :(

Answer (score 3):

If you need the current Model you can use the [initialize()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#Component::initialize) or [startup()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#Component::startup) callback of the Component.

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    $this->Controller = $controller;
    $this->Model = $this->Controller->{$this->Controller->modelClass};
    $this->modelAlias = $this->Model->alias;
    parent::initialize($controller);
}
```

Now you can access the model everywhere in your component.

```
public function countAllItems() {
    return $this->Model->find('count');
}
```