# Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Tags: file, cakephp, upload

```
public function upload ($data = null) {
    foreach ($data as $file) {
        $filename = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $dir = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'uploads';
        $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

        if (!in_array(substr(strrchr($filename, '.'),1) , $allowed)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Error Processing Request", 1);
        }
        elseif (is_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name)) {
            $new_filename = DS.STring::uuid().'-'.$filename;
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,$dir.$new_filename);

            if ($this->Upload->save($this->request->data)) {
            `$this->Session->setFlash('Data Saved!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I got this error..

> Call to a member function save() on a non-object

How to can I fix this?

Comment: Where is this function? inside a controller? if that, what is the name of controller?

Comment: It is inside t he Component folder.. UploadComponent.php

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Upload');
```

then use

```
 $model->save();
```

use

```
if (ClassRegistry::init('Upload')->save($this->request->data)) {

            }
```

Comment: Call to undefined method UploadComponent::loadModel()

Comment: is this a component action?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention it earlier.

Comment: Where will I put these? Sorry.. Newbie :/

Comment: Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object

Comment: return true . and use it in your controller. this is the proper cakephp way.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you pluralized the name of the controller and its filename (and also the table name), i.e. UploadsControllerl? It's a [CakePHP convention](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html):

> Controller class names are plural, CamelCased, and end in Controller. PeopleController and LatestArticlesController are both examples of conventional controller names.

**Edit:**
I thought your method was in a controller class. In a component, before using a model you need to register it as follows:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Yourmodel');
```

so you should use:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Upload');
$model->save($this->request->data);
```

see: [Use a model in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861623/use-a-model-in-a-component)

Comment: That is not a controller class. It is a component.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to these lines? Did you change "$this->Upload->save()" with "$model->save()"? [ClassRegistry::init](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init) is exactly for this purpose unless you don't have an Upload model class.

Comment: I have a model, but this is the only code I use in model.. <?php

class Upload extends AppModel {

}

?>

Comment: The codes I used is from here so you can see the contents of the codes.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scZeqDLxeqM

Answer (score 1):

use ClassRegistry if you are using model in component or in other modles if it has no association.
use

```
ClassRegistry::init('Upload');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please load the model in your controller function suppose you are work with users table then you load the User model in the function $this->loadmodel('User');
 after then you can use the code

```
if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
     your code......
```

}